# Euler Project, #7 - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I'm trying to find the 10,001st prime #.   Here's my code -

```
counter = 3
primes = [1]

while len(primes) < 10002:
    for i in range(2, counter):
        if counter % i == 0:
            counter += 1
    else:
        primes.append(counter)
        counter += 1

print counter
```

So what I get as an output in primes is a list of numbers, the first few numbers are 1, 3, 5, 7, 11... so far, so good... 13, 17, 19, 23, 27... wait, 27?  So at that point it breaks down and starts returning mostly primes but not all primes.  And it takes forever.

I'm new to programming, made it through CodeAcademy's Python course and now trying to figure out how to get past what was essentially just an introduction to the grammar.  I don't come from a math background, so while I know what a prime is, I know there are far better ways to go about this.  If there's anyone in a similar boat who wants to "partner up" and work together on learning Py2.7, I'm more than happy to.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Ugh, thanks for pointing that out.  I'll edit my post, but this code is working to pull a few primes, but is returning 27 and from then on it doesn't pull every number, but the numbers it's returning may or may not be primes.  Doesn't work for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I won't implement anything for you, since that's why you're doing Project Euler, but I will point you strongly in the direction of [The Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). It will calculate in seconds what your code will do in hours.

It works as such: (in pseudocode)

```
for known_prime in a huge list of numbers:
    k=2
    while known_prime*k < the biggest number:
        known_prime*k is not prime
        k += 1
```

Once you've made it through sqrt of the list, you've found every prime number within the list.

Comment: Awesome - thanks so much for that, I'll have to put in some time learning about the sieve, and appreciate you not just implementing for me.

Comment: @monebarrow No problem, it's how I learned it! If you like my answer, please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Done.  Still getting used to this forum, obviously.  Thanks again!

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks again - did a bunch of research and spent 4+ hours last night programming a prime finder using the Sieve of Eratosthenes method.  I feel like it's still mostly a brute force solution and could probably be done in 1/10th the amount of code, but it's a super neat concept and was a great puzzle for me.  Thanks again!

Comment: @monebarrow You're welcome again! Glad to see you excited about coding!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing a project Euler puzzle, you obviously want comments on your code rather than the solution.

Your code:

```
counter = 3
primes = [1]

while len(primes) < 10002:
    for i in range(2, counter):
        if counter % i == 0:
            counter += 1
    else: # Mis-aligned else (assuming it's intended for the if)
        primes.append(counter)
        counter += 1

print counter
```

1. Your `else` is mis-aligned with the `if`
2. Your `for` loop goes all the way to `counter`, and testing divisibility against itself is bound to find remainder 0.
3. Your `else` clause will hit for each non-factor of `counter`. Most numbers will not be a factor, so you don't want to take action in that case. Instead break out of the loop when the `if` part triggers.
4. After exiting the for loop, you'll want to check if a factor was found and if not, add `counter` to your list of primes.

Looks like you are trying to implement a naive un-optimized brute force search, and that is fine.

Maybe try and write out the algorithm in words or pseudo code before coding it.

Comment: Awesome!  The way you responded helps me a lot for where I am right now in my programming journey - a naive, brute force programmer.  I'll get a ton out of this, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As an exercise for you instead of writing for you a simple step by step code I will write a complex line of code with a solution to a similar problem.

Try to figure out what is going on here in this line as an exercise to understand python. 
This code will find the prime numbers until n number not the first n prime numbers that you want

```
def primes(n):
   return sorted(set(range(2, n+1)) - set([p*i for p in range(2, n+1) for i in range(p, n+1)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write an efficient and smart code, you may use the Sieve of Eratosthenes, a good algorithm for finding prime numbers in a given range. 
For more information, read this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

def is_prime(limit):
    aval = True
    for j in range(2,int(limit**0.5)+1):
        if limit == 2:
            aval = True
            break
        elif limit % j == 0:
            aval = False
            break
    return aval
counter = 0
for i in range(2,1000000):
    if is_prime(i):
        counter += 1
        if counter == 10001:
            print("the 10001th prime number is: ",i)
            break

print("seconds: ", time.time() - start_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to this problem. It may not be so quick but it is not precisely for problem 7.

```
import time
start = time.time()

n = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
def nth_prime(n):
    primes = [2]
    x = 3
    max_amount = int(input('How much would you like to go for?: '))
    while True:
        try:
            while x < max_amount:
                for i in primes:
                    if x % i == 0:
                        break
                else:
                    primes.append(x)
                x += 2
            print(primes[n])
        except IndexError:
            max_amount = int(input("Please enter a greater number: "))
            continue
        else:
            print(f('Good job. You\'ve found the {n+1}st prime number :) ')
            break
nth_prime(n)

end = time.time()
print(str(float(end - start)) + " seconds")
```